# How to use angular charts for ionic along with Data taken from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

My controller.js is as follows:

```
.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope,TestMethod,$cordovaSQLite) {
      var dis_stime = [];
      var dis_steps = [];
      $scope.select = function() {
        console.log("check1");
        var lastSynced = localStorage.getItem('lastSynced');
        if (lastSynced != undefined) {
              console.log("check2");
         // alert("lastSynced time is "+lastSynced);
        //  alert("query written");
          try {
                db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name:"health.db",location:'default'});
              //  alert("inside create");
                } catch (error) {
                  alert(error);
                }
          lastSynced = lastSynced * 1000000;
          startTime = lastSynced - (86400 * 1000000000);
          for (var i = 1; i < (PERIOD +1); i++) {
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"SELECT SUM(stepcount) AS total FROM activity WHERE startTime BETWEEN ? AND ?", [startTime,lastSynced])
                  .then(function (resultSet)
                  {
                      dis_stime[i] = lastSynced;
                      dis_steps[i] = resultSet.rows.item(0).total;
                      alert("total  is " + resultSet.rows.item(0).total);
                     // alert("Total is : " +resultSet.rows.item(0).total);
                    //  alert("total entries" + resultSet.rows.length);
                  }, function(error) {
                      alert('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
                    });
                    lastSynced = startTime;
                    startTime = startTime - (86400 * 1000000000);
                  }
                }
            else
            {
              alert("Please sync the device to see the data");
            }
            alert("steps: "+dis_steps+" times: "+dis_stime);
            $scope.labels = dis_stime;
            $scope.series = ['steps'];
            $scope.data = dis_steps;
          }
    })
```

I am fetching the data from sqlite plugin and then i want to display it on graph.

The problem is that the graph doesnt get loaded when select function is called.

where and how should i call the select function so that data is loaded when i open the page??

Comment: For me your code is working. Have you add the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the $cordovaSQLite service in your controller :

```
  .controller('profile',['$scope','http','insert','$cordovaSQLite',
             function($scope,$http,insert,$cordovaSQLite){
       ...
    }]);
```